# Disable input type radio button click from cs page and send alert to user using js?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, web

i have a radio button which is disable for managers but enable for otherrs it need to handle from cs page radio button onclick .the code to disable radio from aspx is

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="myButton" value="theValue"
onclick="this.checked=false;
alert('Sorry, this option is not for manager!')">
```

how to do it in cs page i am doing

```
rbtnOpen.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "this.checked=false; alert('Sorry, this option is not available!')");
```

its working fine and also showing the alert but when but page is refreshing .
let say i have 3 stat A,B,C....
for an iten B is selected radio for manager if he clicks A or C is should prompt the alert after closing the alert it should again show B ..in my case its prompting the alert but all the radio button become uncheck

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script>
            function check()
            {

             alert('Sorry, this option is not available!');
             document.getElementById("b").checked=true;
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            A<input type="radio" name="gender" id="a" value="a" onclick="check()"/>
            B<input type="radio" name="gender" id="b" value="b" />
            C<input type="radio" name="gender" id="c" value="c" onclick="check()"/>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you completely disable the control for managers, instead of displaying it as a clickable input? That way you'd make it even more clear that managers cannot use that option.